# Rails & Postgresql on AWS Cloud 9 : role "ec2-user" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, aws-cloud9

I am trying to get my Rails environment up and running with a Postgres database using AWS Cloud9 and have run into a problem when trying run `rails db:migrate`.

Initially I created the project by running:

1. **rails new app_name -d postgresql**
2. **bundle install**

Bundler had a problem finding `gem 'pg'` so I ran:

1. **sudo yum install postgresql-devel**
2. **sudo yum install postgresql-server**
3. **sudo postgresql initdb**
4. **sudo service postgresql start**

The server fired up fine afterwards and I thought all was well until running `rails db:migrate` which returned the error:

**PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "ec2-user" does not exist**

I am unsure how to fix this.

It has been suggested that I may need to get into my psql shell and alter or create a new role, but I'm unsure how to alter the `ec2-user`.

It has also been suggested that my `pg_hba.conf` file may need some alterations.  I have the path to that file, but am not sure how to edit it or if that's something that I really want to do.

Any suggestions?  I'm including my `database.yml` below:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_production
  username: my_app
  password: <%= ENV['MY_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: When you log into an ec2 instance, AWS brings you in as `ec2-user`. You are executing the `rails db:migrate` command as that user. PG cannot find that user in the DB. I believe you can create that user in the DB as you started here `It has been suggested that I may need to get into my psql shell and alter or create a new role` or I believe you can create a new linux user that matches the username in the DB. If I could recall the exact steps, I would have posted the answer, but I cannot remember them.

Comment: @NicholasMartinez ok, that makes sense I think.  So I would need to get into psql and create a user named "ec2-user"? And..if AWS "brings you in as ec2-user", wouldn't there be a password attached to that user as well?  How would I find that?  Much appreciated Nicholas.

Comment: You can run something like this in your console to create the user `sudo -u postgres createuser -s ec2-user`.

Comment: Hmm..  that gave me `createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "ec2-user" already exists`  I wonder what the conflict is.

Comment: Give this one a shot `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: So I'm not sure what happened.  I ran `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` and the migration went through successfully. BUT when I run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` i get a peer authentication error.  I think that I might just need to create a user/role for `veggie_app`.  Thanks again for your help.  I can hopefully figure it out from here.... maybe. At least everything is working fine in development  : )

Comment: Sounds great. Good luck.

Comment: Just curious if you got it figured out.

Comment: Yeah.  Thanks again for the help.  It was a pretty obvious oversight on my part.  The Peer authentication error (and probably the previous original errors) came from the password & username being set for the production db in my `database.yml` file.  I removed those for now and all is well.

Comment: **STEP 3** for me was: `sudo service postgresql initdb`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every user of `psql` also needs a corresponding database that matches their name.

At the bash command line:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -s ec2-user
sudo -u postgres createdb ec2-user
```

The above should allow your user to access `psql`, but it won't let rails make migrations yet. You'll have to do the following first:

```
sudo su postgres
psql
ALTER USER "ec2-user" WITH SUPERUSER;
\q
exit
```

I put that together quite quickly so let me know if you run into any problems.

If your `config/database.yml` is using a different login user to your bash user, you should repeat all above steps for that user as well.

Lastly, although you are on Cloud9, this is just a simple Rails/Postgres issue, rather than an AWS issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had already managed to get it sorted out, but I believe this is similar to what I ended up doing.  And to add to the above answer, from what I gather, it is probably best to not to create the db for ec2-user (the root user) but instead create a new role in in AWS/IAM settings and create the project with that role (?)...

Comment: Yep, you are right. Root should really be used mainly for IAM stuff - Users with specific permissions should be used when creating and working on AWS resources.